# Automating PUSH notification

Tags: appium

Is it possible to automate push notifications in Android emulator using Appium?
How can we slide down the notification handle and select appropriate application notification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can Open Notifications using

```
driver.openNotifications();
```

You can Scroll down to your Notification

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("Element Name"));
HashMap<String, String> arguments = new HashMap<String, String>();
arguments.put("element", element.getId());
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("mobile: scrollTo", arguments);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! So, openNotifications() will scroll down the notification screen by itself? or Do I need to scroll it explicitly?

Comment: Also, I have declare my driver to AppiumDriver so that at run-time I can initialize it to either AndroidDriver or IosDriver, but I cannot see openNotofication() in the list of methods.  If I declare my instance to AndroidDriver only then I am able to see that

Comment: I have tried with AndroidDriver and its working, try with AndroidDriver and if still the method not visible add one dependency for Java-Client Use this Link https://github.com/appium/java-client, let me know if it works,